# Writing to complex PDF's in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, pdf-generation, matlab-figure

I'm trying to write a MATLAB function that processes a file and writes a report on that file. The report will contain numbers, strings, tables, and images.

After looking at MATLAB's documentation, I can only find functions that save individual items to a file. For example, print saves a plot, write saves a table, etc. How do I create a single file that contains many of these items (e.g. a PDF with images, tables, and text)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `print` with the `-append` option to write multiple pages to a PostScript file in sequence, and then convert the ps to pdf. Using Matlab's handle graphics system, it is possible (if tedious) to design each print page in detail, arrange elements, etc.

However, if your document is going to be really complex, I think it would be better to generate the pdf in another way. One approach would be to write LaTeX code using lots of `fprintf`s and compile the file using `pdflatex`.

Btw., I'm not aware of a Matlab function `write` that generates a pdf.

Comment: You could use the Matlab FEX http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19516-ps2pdf